# Returning only first element of a sub array with $elemMatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using node and mongoose, and have a schema that looks like this:

```
var SubscriberSchema = new Schema({
    'user': [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    'level': { type: String, enum: [ 'owner', 'sub', 'commenter', 'poster' ] }
    'dateAdded': { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

// Group Schema
var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    'groupOwner': [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    'groupName': String,
    'subscribers': [SubscriberSchema],
});
```

I would like to query the group to find all groups where a user (stored in `req.user._id` via token authentication) is a subscriber (i.e. their `_id` is in the `subscribers` array), and only return the single subscribers array element with their `_id`.

I've read the Mongo documentation on [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) as this seems to be what I need, and built the query below. This returns the information I want, but returns all elements of the `subscribers` array. How can I return only the single element of the `subscribers` array that matches my `req.user._id`?

Current query, returns all elements of `subscribers`:

```
            Group
                .find( { "subscribers.user": req.user._id}, { subscribers: { $elemMatch: { user: req.user._id }}} )
                .sort('groupName')
                .populate('groupOwner', 'email firstName lastName')
                .populate('subscribers.user', 'email firstName lastName')
                .exec(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error('Unable to retrieve groups for user: ' + err.message);
                        res.status(500)
                    } else {
                        res.json(data);
                    }
                });
```

This returns the following for subscribers (via `util.inspect(data[0].subscribers)`):

```
Subscribers
 [{ 
  user: 
   [ { _id: 1234,
       email: 'me@here.com',
       firstName: 'Testy',
       lastName: 'Testelson' } ] }
  user: 
   [ { _id: 5678,
       email: 'you@there.com',
       firstName: 'Biggy',
       lastName: 'Smalls' } ] }]
```

Based on the $elemMatch docs, I would assume I would only see user 1234 since that's the record that matches `req.user._id`. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your projection parameter, use the [dollar operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

```
{"user.$": 1}
```

This will return a Group with only a single object in its 'subscribers' array.